# How to use 2 xpaths to send keys (elements from a dictionary) via loop on Python? Selenium related

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to automate a process on this [page](https://opensea.io/asset/create), and I'm stuck at the part where I need to take the `keys` and `values` from a dictionary called `current_dictionary` and paste them into the `Type` and `Name` textboxes, here's the code I have managed to do so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222") #this allows bulk-dozer to take control of your Chrome Browser in DevTools mode.
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions

def wait_xpath(code): #function to wait for the element to be located by its XPATH
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, code)))

current_dictionary = {'Background': 'Ocean',
                      'Body': 'Crab',
                      'Colour': 'Dark green',
                      'Eyes type': 'Antennae',
                      'Claws': 'None',
                      'Spikes': 'None'}

if driver.current_url == 'https://opensea.io/asset/create':
    button_plus_properties = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div[2]/form/section/div[1]/div/div[2]/button').click() #click on the "+" button of Properties
    wait_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div') #wait for "Add properties" dialog to be loaded and located
```

After having logged in to this site with the Metamask extension, the code above will look for the `+` button from the `Properties` element and click on it:

[image: button +]

Then, it will wait until this dialog has been located:

[image: preview1]

I know I can use `list(current_dictionary.keys())` and `list(current_dictionary.values())` to get the corresponding arrays of both elements in the `current_dictionary`:

```
In [120]: list(current_dictionary.keys())
Out[120]: ['Background', 'Body', 'Colour', 'Eyes type', 'Claws', 'Spikes']

In [121]  list(current_dictionary.values())
Out[121]: ['Ocean', 'Crab', 'Dark green', 'Antennae', 'None', 'None']
```

And I have observed that the following paths from this page can be used for looping:

```
xpath_type = '/html/body/div/div/div/div/section/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/input'
xpath_name = '/html/body/div/div/div/div/section/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/input'
```

For instance: If I paste the `xpath_type` in to the `Xpath search bar` within the html source of this page and press several times `Enter`:
[image: XPATH preview]

It can be seen that it will iterate over the `Type` textboxes, the same applies for the `Name` textboxes and the `xpath_name`.

So, how could I code a loop that manage to get the following output? (assume there are 6 textboxes available for `Type` element and `Name` element as well):

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when trying to use the **XPATHs** in this page, they ended up breaking after the first try, not sure why it happened.

However, their corresponding `CSS_SELECTOR` counterparts did manage to fulfill my expectations pretty well.

Here's the solution:

```
###improvements were applied from this part 

if driver.current_url == 'https://opensea.io/asset/create':
    button_plus_properties = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section/div[2]/form/section/div[1]/div/div[2]/button').click() #click on the "+" button of Properties
    wait_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div') #wait for "Add properties" dialog to be loaded and located
type_array = list(current_dictionary.keys()) #get the keys which will be send as types
name_array = list(current_dictionary.values()) #get the values which will be send as values 
i = 1
while i <= len(current_dictionary): #iterate over the types and values lulz
    css_type = f'body > div:nth-child(25) > div > div > div > section > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td:nth-child(1) > div > div > input' #selector of the i type 
    css_name = f'body > div:nth-child(25) > div > div > div > section > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td:nth-child(2) > div > div > input' #selector of the i value
    button_css_type = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_type).send_keys(type_array[i-1]) #find the ith textbox type and paste the ith-1 element from the type_array variable
    button_css_name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_name).send_keys(name_array[i-1]) #find the ith textbox value and paste the ith-1 element from the name_array variable  
    if i != len(current_dictionary): #as long as i is not equal to the lenght of the current_dictionary
        button_add_more = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/section/button').click() #add a new textbox type and textbox value
    i +=1
button_save_metadata = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/footer/button') #find the save button in this dialog
button_save_metadata.click() #save the metadata
```

The improvement above first creates an array for both `Type` and `Name` elements to store the **Keys** and **Values** of the `current_dictionary` respectively.

Then, it will start a while loop, in which it is set the general `CSS_SELECTOR` for any new textbox created after clicking the `Add more` button until the counter `i` is equal to the **lenght** of the `current_dictionary`, then it sends the corresponding Key and Value to their respective textboxes, and finally it saves everything by clicking the `Save` button.

**Output**:
[image: solution]